# How to POST/PUT a model without a wrapper object with Symfony2 form?

Tags: rest, symfony, symfony-forms, fosrestbundle

I'm using FOSRestBundle and I'm trying to POST/PUT json model.

an article model is something like:

```
{
    "id": 456,
    "body": "Lorem ipsum dolor sid amet"
}
```

Currently, if I do a POST/PUT on my controller action, I need to do:

```
POST /articles
{
    "article": {
        "body": "Lorem ipsum dolor sid amet"
    }
}
```

But I'd like to do:

```
POST /articles
{
    "body": "Lorem ipsum dolor sid amet"
}
```

Note that the JSON object is automatically deserialized in Request object by Symfony2.

**How could I remove the prefix key of the object?**

Answer (score 0):

In your ArticleType Class:

```
public function getName() {
    return null;
}
```

This should work.